# DynamoDB Query based on an attribute in a list of objects

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am having the below record in dynamo db table.

```
    {

       "Key" : "key1",
        listvalue:[
           {"attrib1":"attribv1", "attrib2":"attribv2" },
           {"attrib1": "attribv3", "attrib2": "attribv4"}
           ]
    }
```

I need to query dynamo db table to get the whole record which is having "attrib1" attribute value as "attribv1" in nodejs. Please let me know if this is possible

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to filter by `attrib1` attribute alone as the object has two attributes `attrib1` and `attrib2`. You need both the attribute values to use `contains` function to get the item.

> CONTAINS is supported for lists: When evaluating "a CONTAINS b", "a"
>   can be a list; however, "b" cannot be a set, a map, or a list.